# Supabase rc 2 typescript types from remote db

Tags: typescript, types, supabase, supabase-database

For supabase 1 there was open-api to generate types for typescript which is pretty clear: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/generating-types
`npx openapi-typescript https://your-project.supabase.co/rest/v1/?apikey=your-anon-key --output types/supabase.ts`

But I am not able to use them with supabase rc 2.
[image]

So I assume I need to follow the new documentation, but there is no description of how to do it. There is only one for local DB. Plus I found `--db-url` flag but not more info regarding that.

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/next/typescript-support

I have tried this command: `npx supabase gen types typescript --db-url https://your-project.supabase.co > src/database.types.ts`, but I am getting error: `Error: URL is not a valid Supabase connection string.`

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

for --db-url use the connection string shown under /settings/database, I used the node version. It should look something like

```
postgresql://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.[YOUR-PROJECT-REF].supabase.co:5432/postgres
```

Comment: This moved me to the next step, thank you. It run that command, but I am getting error: `Error: error running container`

Comment: It seems that I have issue with connecting to database via uri. I am getting error: ```failed: Connection refused. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?```

Comment: @Dawe You need to be using your own project reference and not the one posted in HotCustard's example. You also need to have docker running on your computer as it's a requirement for the types generation code.

Comment: @AndrewSmith I have all of this, and of course, I am using my project URL. Docker is running - have docker desktop. I also used it to get types from local DB (I just pulled schema to local via supabase-cli), but it is not much comfortable

Comment: @Dawe Sounds like your --db-url is pointing to a locally hosted version, but the local version is not running. You can point to the supabase hosted version and bypass needing a local version. If you want it generating from local then you will need to work out what the correct connection string should be based on your local setup.

Comment: @HotCustard --db-url gets remote url (which I get on my project at supabase.com). For local URL I use `supabase gen types typescript --local` this command, which works correctly.